# How delete duplicate files ending with " - Copy" in cmd

Tags: cmd

By accident, I ended up duplicating a load of files which I know want to delete. I want to delete the files recursively from my documents folder. While in my documents directory, I type the following to list the files for a safety check before deleting:

```
dir * - Copy*.*/s
```

But it lists files which do not follow the above sequence. Most of them do not even end with " - Copy". I Would appreciate a hand before I delete them. By the way, I am deleting roughly 400-600 files, so doing it by hand would be very tedious.

Comment: `dir "* - Copy*.*" /s`

Comment: @Ben, Thanks. And just to confirm I should use del "* - Copy*.*" /s  to delete the files?

Comment: No. I'd prefer using Powershell on that X)

Comment: @BenRogers You could do so,  to be sure add the `/P` switch del will ask you to confirm every deletion. `del /P /S "* - Copy*.*"`

Comment: `del "* -Copy*.*" /s`  did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a simple way.
You can use the search bar in the top corner with the "- Copy" keyword. And after the files are displayed, you can select all files (CTRL + A) and delete them.